# scala - can't existentially abstract over parameterized type

Tags: scala

In this simple example, I create a create a container class over a generic type:

```
class  Student[T](val favoriteThing:T, var partner:Option[Student[T]]=None )
```

The first field `favoriteThing` is of generic type `T` and the second field is a pointer to another instance of the class, but in an `Option` type, and it has a default value of `None`.

I can instantiate this class and examine the first field

```
val s1 = new Student(42)
s1.favoriteThing
```

But get this runtime error when accessing the `partner` field.

```
s1.partner
Compiler exception error: line 0: can't existentially abstract over parameterized type Student[Int]
  def apply() = {
            ^
```

Appreciate any help in understanding this error.

Comment: Something seems to be missing as the code above runs smoothly for me. What scala version are you using?

Comment: You probably have an unbound *Type Constructor* in a *block*. LIke `{class A[B] {}; new A[Int]}`. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122398/cant-existentially-abstract-over-parameterized-type?rq=1

Comment: Please post more relevant code and what you have posted works fine.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg Same behaviour for me. It just works.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - I had been testing with scalafiddle

http://scalafiddle.net/console/e25f42d74afdf8c6ca6a3b7ece3af051

And that seems to be the source of the problem. Will be more cautious with scalafiddle in the future...

Answer (score 0):

This was not a problem with scala. The issue was in using scalafiddle

http://scalafiddle.net/console/e25f42d74afdf8c6ca6a3b7ece3af051

This compiles and runs properly outside of that context.