# Is there any way to map over a collection of values of a type parameterized with a higher type?

Tags: scala, existential-type, higher-kinded-types, higher-rank-types

I read existing questions about how type definitions with parameterized bounds are illegal inside blocks (or something to that effect), but it doesn't help me in my problem:

```
type Cons[X]

class Higher[C[X] <: Cons[X]]
type AnyHigher = Higher[C] forSome { type C[X] <: Cons[X] }

Seq[AnyHigher]().map { h => h }
```

compiler:

```
can't existentially abstract over parameterized type C
Seq[AnyHigher]().map { h => h }
```

The element type of the input collection is irrelevant, the problem lies only in the return type of the mapping function. Is there any way around this? I tried various refactors: making the mapping function a method, cheating by making the code generic and executing parameterized with `AnyHigher`, writing my own recursion, but nothing helps.

Comment: Are you sure you need existentials? they are notoriously difficult to understand and use and there was even an attempt to remove them from the language.

Comment: Yes, they aren't there in Scala 3. But unfortunately, I don't think there is another way to define `LUB` of all `Higher` instances. And the whole 'parameterized with a type constructor' is absolutely central to the project, there is no way I can really change the definition. At worst, I'll introduce a sealed, non-parameterized type with a casting method down to the existential type.

Comment: why exactly do you want to abstract over all higher? have you looked at a **typeclass** instead?

Comment: Type classes are for types. Here I don't have a type only a type constructor, because I use phantom types for type-level indexing of `Higher` Also, type class would make sense if there where may different types of `Higher` while there is only one (when, a couple, but it is `Const` which is an actual variable and the payload of the whole design.

Comment: so **Monad** is not a typeclass because it works on type constructors _(which btw are also types)_?  - If there is only one **Cons** what is the point of abstracting? - Finally, I am not saying that a typeclass would be the solution I just asked why you need this since it is not clear from the question  and just said that maybe a typeclass would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is

```
Seq[AnyHigher]().map(new (AnyHigher => AnyHigher) {
  override def apply(h: AnyHigher): AnyHigher = h
})
```

["can't existentially abstract over parameterized type..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122398/cant-existentially-abstract-over-parameterized-type)

Another workaround is to make `C[X]` a type member rather than type parameter

```
type Cons[X]

class Higher {
  type C[X] <: Cons[X]
}
object Higher {
  type Aux[C0[X0] <: Cons[X0]] = Higher { type C[X] = C0[X] }
}

type AnyHigher = Higher

Seq[AnyHigher]().map(h => h)
```

and use `Higher.Aux[C]` instead of `Higher[C]` and `Higher` instead of `Higher[C] forSome { type C[X] <: Cons[X] }`.

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html

https://scalacenter.github.io/scala-3-migration-guide/docs/incompatibilities/dropped-features.html#existential-type

> Existential type is a dropped feature, which makes the following code
> illegal.
>
> ```
> def foo: List[Class[T]] forSome { type T }
> ```
>
> The proposed solution is to introduce an enclosing type that carries a
> dependent type:
>
> ```
> trait Bar {   
>   type T   
>   val value: List[Class[T]] 
> }
>
> def foo: Bar
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Quick as ever :) I know they are being dropped, but in Scala 3 this works without exitentials, the wildcard stands for any kind. I am trying to code with mind of planned changes, but unfortunately too often scala 3 style doesn't compile in `2.13`

Answer (score 0):

Why @Dmytro Mitin's answer is the correct one as both type safe, and offering a local solution not needing changes to the types, it is a bit of a mouthful. So, at least temporarily, I opted for introducing a super type and  casting:

```scala
    sealed trait AnyHigher {
        def apply() :Higher[T] forSome { type T[O] <: Cons[O] } =
            this.asInstanceOf[Higher[T] forSome { type T[O] <: Cons[O] }]
    }
    
    class Higher[T[O] <: Cons[O]] extends AnyHigher

    Seq[AnyHigher]().map(t => t)
```

It's ugly, but a bit less and it's temoporary until Scala 3, which has wildcard types covering any kinds.