# "Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement"

Tags: scala

When I compile:

```
object Test extends App {
  implicit def pimp[V](xs: Seq[V]) = new {
    def dummy(x: V) = x
  }
}
```

I get:

```
$ fsc -d aoeu go.scala
go.scala:3: error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
    def dummy(x: V) = x
        ^
one error found
```

Why?

([Scala: "Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685804/) doesn't really answer this.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's disallowed by the spec. See *3.2.7 Compound Types*.

> Within a method declaration in a structural reﬁnement, the type of any value parameter may only refer to type parameters or abstract types that are contained inside the reﬁnement. That is, it must refer either to a type parameter of the method
>   itself, or to a type deﬁnition within the reﬁnement. This restriction does not apply
>   to the function’s result type.

Before [Bug 1906](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1906) was fixed, the compiler would have compiled this and you'd have gotten a method not found at runtime. This was fixed in [revision 19442](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/19442) and this is why you get this wonderful message.

The question is then, why is this not allowed?

Here is very [detailed explanation](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Structural-types-with-generic-type-question-tp1992248p1992249.html) from Gilles Dubochet from the scala mailing list back in 2007. It roughly boils down to the fact that structural types use reflection and the compiler does not know how to look up the method to call if it uses a type defined outside the refinement (the compiler does not know ahead of time how to fill the second parameter of *getMethod* in `p.getClass.getMethod("pimp", Array(?))`

But go look at the post, it will answer your question and some more.

Edit:

Hello list.

> I try to define structural types with abstract datatype in function
>   parameter. ... Any reason?

I have heard about two questions concerning the structural typing
extension of Scala 2.6 lately, and I would like to answer them here.

1. Why did we change Scala's native values (“int”, etc.) boxing scheme
   to Java's (“java.lang.Integer”).
2. Why is the restriction on parameters for structurally defined
   methods (“Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer
   to abstract type defined outside that same refinement”) required.

Before I can answer these two questions, I need to speak about the
implementation of structural types.

The JVM's type system is very basic (and corresponds to Java 1.4). That
means that many types that can be represented in Scala cannot be
represented in the VM. Path dependant types (“x.y.A”), singleton types
(“a.type”), compound types (“A with B”) or abstract types are all types
that cannot be represented in the JVM's type system.

To be able to compile to JVM bytecode, the Scala compilers changes the
Scala types of the program to their “erasure” (see section 3.6 of the
reference). Erased types can be represented in the VM's type system and
define a type discipline on the program that is equivalent to that of
the program typed with Scala types (saving some casts), although less
precise. As a side note, the fact that types are erased in the VM
explains why operations on the dynamic representation of types (pattern
matching on types) are very restricted with respect to Scala's type
system.

Until now all type constructs in Scala could be erased in some way.
This isn't true for structural types. The simple structural type “{ def
x: Int }” can't be erased to “Object” as the VM would not allow
accessing the “x” field. Using an interface “interface X { int x{}; }”
as the erased type won't work either because any instance bound by a
value of this type would have to implement that interface which cannot
be done in presence of separate compilation. Indeed (bear with me) any
class that contains a member of the same name than a member defined in
a structural type anywhere would have to implement the corresponding
interface. Unfortunately this class may be defined even before the
structural type is known to exist.

Instead, any reference to a structurally defined member is implemented
as a reflective call, completely bypassing the VM's type system. For
example `def f(p: { def x(q: Int): Int }) = p.x(4)` will be rewritten
to something like:

```
  def f(p: Object) = p.getClass.getMethod("x", Array(Int)).invoke(p, Array(4))
```

And now the answers.

1. “invoke” will use boxed (“java.lang.Integer”) values whenever the
   invoked method uses native values (“int”). That means that the above
   call must really look like “...invoke(p, Array(new
   java.lang.Integer(4))).intValue”.

Integer values in a Scala program are already often boxed (to allow the
“Any” type) and it would be wasteful to unbox them from Scala's own
boxing scheme to rebox them immediately as java.lang.Integer.

Worst still, when a reflective call has the “Any” return type,
what should be done when a java.lang.Integer is returned? The called
method may either be returning an “int” (in which case it should be
unboxed and reboxed as a Scala box) or it may be returning a
java.lang.Integer that should be left untouched.

Instead we decided to change Scala's own boxing scheme to Java's. The
two previous problems then simply disappear. Some performance-related
optimisations we had with Scala's boxing scheme (pre-calculate the
boxed form of the most common numbers) were easy to use with Java
boxing too. In the end, using Java boxing was even a bit faster than
our own scheme.

2. “getMethod”'s second parameter is an array with the types of the
   parameters of the (structurally defined)  method to lookup — for
   selecting which method to get when the name is overloaded. This is the
   one place where exact, static types are needed in the process of
   translating a structural member call. Usually, exploitable static types
   for a method's parameter are provided with the structural type
   definition. In the example above, the parameter type of “x” is known to
   be “Int”, which allows looking it up.

Parameter types defined as abstract types where the abstract type is
defined inside the scope of the structural refinement are no problem
either:
  def f(p: { def x[T](t: T): Int }) = p.xInt
In this example we know that any instance passed to “f” as “p” will
define “x[T](t: T)” which is necessarily erased to  “x(t: Object)”. The
lookup is then correctly done on the erased type:
  def f(p: Object) = p.getClass.getMethod("x", Array(Object)).invoke(p,
Array(new java.lang.Integer(4)))

But if an abstract type from outside the structural refinement's scope
is used to define a parameter of a structural method, everything breaks:
  def f[T](p: { def x(t: T): Int }, t: T) = p.x(t)
When “f” is called, “T” can be instantiated to any type, for example:
  f[Int]({ def x(t: Int) = t }, 4)
  f[Any]({ def x(t: Any) = 5 }, 4)
The lookup for the first case would have to be “getMethod("x",
Array(int))” and for the second “getMethod("x", Array(Object))”, and
there is no way to know which one to generate in the body of
“f”: “p.x(t)”.

To allow defining a unique “getMethod” call inside “f”'s body for
any instantiation of “T” would require any object passed to “f” as the
“p” parameter to have the type of “t” erased to “Any”.  This would be a
transformation where the type of a class' members depend on how
instances of this class are used in the program. And this is something
we definitely don't want to do (and can't be done with separate
compilation).

Alternatively, if Scala supported run-time types one could use them to
solve this problem. Maybe one day ...

But for now, using abstract types for structural method's parameter
types is simply forbidden.

Sincerely,
Gilles.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work? The compiler could find the type if it tried really hard.

Answer (score 12):

Discovered the problem shortly after posting this: I have to define a named class instead of using an anonymous class.  (Still would love to hear a better explanation of the reasoning though.)

```
object Test extends App {
  case class G[V](xs: Seq[V]) {
    def dummy(x: V) = x
  }
  implicit def pimp[V](xs: Seq[V]) = G(xs)
}
```

works.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, because it fixed my problem too.  And from the solution I can finally reverse engineer what the error was referring to;  the accepted answer above didn't help me with that.