# Is there a trait for "update", similar to Function1 for apply?

Tags: scala, syntax, updates, traits, structural-typing

Scala allows to define `update` such as

```
def update(index: Int, value: String) { ... }
```

and then call it like

```
foo(i) = "Text"
```

Is there a trait that encapsulates that? Something like

```
trait Update1[+A,+B] {
    def update(i: A, v: B)
}
```

(Of course I could define such a trait myself, but it would only work for instances that I mix with it, not with other ones constructed beyond my influence.)

Comment: Why would you need a trait? It's a syntactic feature, it doesn't require type-level support.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I'm creating generic functions that can read values (using an arbitrary `Function1`) as well as update them. If there were a type-level support for it, I could use them for anything that is updatable, not just for classes I create myself.

Comment: I have tried `type Update1[A+, B+] = { def update(i: A, v:B): Unit }`, but [this is not allowed by the compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830731/parameter-type-in-structural-refinement-may-not-refer-to-an-abstract-type-defin), so I tried to declare a specific one `type Update1 = { def update(i: Int, v: String): Unit }` but for some reason this still doesn't work; I tested on ArrayBuffer[String] and got: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.update(int, java.lang.String)`. Not sure why, but you might want to look in this direction.

Comment: ok, the reason why `Update1` didn't work in this case is that at runtime, `String` is erased, and the signature of the value is `Object`, so you could try `type Update1 = { def update(i: Int, v: Object): Unit }`. While you can successfully cast `ArrayBuffer[String]` to `Update1`, you still need to do it explicitly, so I am not sure if it's very useful for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't define such a trait is that you are using covariant type parameters in a place where they are not allowed. The following traits compile fine in Scala 2.10:

```
trait Update1[-A, -B] {
  def update(i: A, v: B) : Unit
}

trait MyFunction1[-A, +B] {
  def apply(a:A): B
}

trait Mutable[-A, B] extends Update1[A,B] with MyFunction1[A,B]
```

Notice that in order to have a mutable trait you have to fix the **B** parameter, so it allows neither covariance nor contravariance. If you take a look at the mutable collections in the Scala API you can see that in fact this is how they are declared.

In addition, nothing prevents you to mix a trait in an object instead of in a class to make the compiler happy, if you know that class already implements the methods defined in the trait. For example, you can have the following:

```
class SingleStringCollection(v: String) extends MyFunction1[Int, String] {
  private var someString: String = v
  def apply(a: Int): String =  someString

  def update(i: Int, v: String): Unit = {
    someString = v
  }
  override def toString = someString
}

val test1: Update1[Int, String] = new SingleStringCollection("hi") // this would fail
val test2: Update1[Int, String] = new SingleStringCollection("hi") with Update1[Int, String] // this would work
```

Or you could also use structural typing if you just want to require that your val or parameter implements a list of known methods:

```
type UpdatableStructuralType = {
  def update(i: Int, v: String) : Unit
}

val test3: UpdatableStructuralType = new SingleStringCollection("hi") // this would work
test3(0) = "great" // And of course this would also work
```

So you have several alternatives if you want to accept parameters conforming to some trait or requiring some methods to be implemented.