# Passing extractors dynamically for pattern matching

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I want to be able to dynamically choose which extractors to use in my case class pattern matching.

I want something like:

```
def handleProcessingResult(extract: SomeType) : PartialFunction[Event, State] = {
    case Event(someEvent: SomeEvent, extract(handlers)) =>
        ...

    case Event(otherEvent: OtherEvent, extract(handlers)) =>
        ...
}
```

The idea is that I can have the above partial function, and can then use it anywhere where I know how to write an `unapply` to match and extract `handlers` from some pattern matched type.

If you are wondering why I want these partial functions, it is so that I can compose partial functions of common behaviour together to form the handlers for my states in an Akka FSM. This is not required to understand the question, but for example:

```
when(ProcessingState) {
    handleProcessingResult(extractHandlersFromProcessing) orElse {
        case Event(Created(path), Processing(handlers)) =>
            ...
    }
}

when(SuspendedState) {
   handleProcessingResult(extractHandlersFromSuspended) orElse {
       case Event(Created(path), Suspended(waiting, Processing(handlers))) =>
           ...
}
```

It seems like this should be possible but I can't figure out how!

I have tried the following two simplifications:

```
object TestingUnapply {

  sealed trait Thing
  case class ThingA(a: String) extends Thing
  case class ThingB(b: String, thingA: ThingA) extends Thing

  val x = ThingA("hello")
  val y = ThingB("goodbye", ThingA("maybe"))

  process(x, new { def unapply(thing: ThingA) = ThingA.unapply(thing)})
  process(y, new { def unapply(thing: ThingB) = ThingB.unapply(thing).map(_._2.a)})


  def process(thing: Thing, extract: { def unapply[T <: Thing](thing: T): Option[String]}) = thing match {
    case extract(a) => s"The value of a is: $a"
  }
}
```

The idea being that I should be able to pass any sub-type of Thing and a suitable extractor to `process`. However, it doesn't compile due to:

```
[error] /tmp/proj1/TestUnapply.scala:10: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : AnyRef{def unapply(thing: TestingUnapply.ThingA): Option[String]}
[error]  required: AnyRef{def unapply[T <: TestingUnapply.Thing](thing: T): Option[String]}
[error]   process(x, new { def unapply(thing: ThingA) = ThingA.unapply(thing)})
[error]              ^
[error] /tmp/proj1/TestUnapply.scala:11: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : AnyRef{def unapply(thing: TestingUnapply.ThingB): Option[String]}
[error]  required: AnyRef{def unapply[T <: TestingUnapply.Thing](thing: T): Option[String]}
[error]   process(y, new { def unapply(thing: ThingB) = ThingB.unapply(thing).map(_._2.a)})
[error]              ^
```

Subsequently, moving the declaration of type parameter `T` onto `process`, gives us:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object TestingUnapply {

  sealed trait Thing
  case class ThingA(a: String) extends Thing
  case class ThingB(b: String, thingA: ThingA) extends Thing

  val x = ThingA("hello")
  val y = ThingB("goodbye", ThingA("maybe"))

  process(x, new { def unapply(thing: ThingA) = ThingA.unapply(thing)})
  process(y, new { def unapply(thing: ThingB) = ThingB.unapply(thing).map(_._2.a)})

  def process[T <: Thing: ClassTag](thing: Thing, extract: { def unapply(thing: T): Option[String]}) = thing match {
    case extract(a) => s"The value of a is: $a"
  }
}
```

Now gives us a different compilation error of:

```
[error] /tmp/TestUnapply.scala:18: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
[error]   def process[T <: Thing: ClassTag](thing: Thing, extract: { def unapply(thing: T): Option[String]}) = thing match {
```

I am most likely doing something daft. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make an workaround based on your first simplification, hope it helps.

```
 object DynamicPattern extends App {

    sealed trait Thing
    case class ThingA(a: String) extends Thing
    case class ThingB(b: String, thingA: ThingA) extends Thing

   // change structural type to an abstract class
   abstract class UniversalExtractor[T <: Thing] {
     def unapply(thing: T): Option[String]
   }

   // extract is an instance of UniversalExtractor with unapply method
   // naturally it's an extractor
   def process[T <: Thing](thing: T, extract: UniversalExtractor[T]) = 
     thing match {
       case extract(a) => s"The value of a is: $a"
     }

   val x = ThingA("hello")
   val y = ThingB("goodbye", ThingA("maybe"))

   val result1 = process(
     x,
     new UniversalExtractor[ThingA] {
        def unapply(thing: ThingA) = ThingA.unapply(thing)
     }
   )

   val result2 = process(y,
     new UniversalExtractor[ThingB] {
        def unapply(thing: ThingB) =   ThingB.unapply(thing).map(_._2.a)
     }
   )

   // result1 The value of a is: hello
   println(" result1 " + result1)
   // result2 The value of a is: maybe
   println(" result2 " + result2)
}
```

**Update**

A probably "nasty" method without using an abstract class or trait hinted by the type conformance problem I explained later.

````
  // when invoking process method, we actually know which subtype of 
  // Thing is pattern-matched, plus the type conformance problem, 
  // so here comes the ```unapply[T <: Thing](thing: T)``` 
  // and ```asInstanceOf(which is usually not that appealing)```. 
  val thingAExtractor = new { 
    def unapply[T <: Thing](thing: T): Option[String] = 
      ThingA.unapply(thing.asInstanceOf[ThingA])
  }

  val thingBExtractor = new {
    def unapply[T <: Thing](thing: T): Option[String] =
      ThingB.unapply(thing.asInstanceOf[ThingB]).map(_._2.a)
  }

  // hello
  println(process(x, thingAExtractor))
  // maybe
  println(process(y, thingBExtractor))
````

---

The reason it doesn't work in the two simplifications(actually the nasty method just pops up in my mind when I try to figure out the reason, so just write it here in case it helps).

For the first simplication: it's about the **`type conformance`** problem.

```
  type ExtractType = { def unapply[T <: Thing](thing: T): Option[String] }
  val anonExtractor = new { def unapply(thing: ThingA) = ThingA.unapply(thing) }

  import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{ TypeTag, typeTag }
  def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag](o: T) = typeTag[T].tpe
  def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag] = ru.typeOf[T]

  // false | so in turn type check fails at compilation time
  println(getTypeTag(anonExtractor) <:< getTypeTag[ExtractType])
```

[ScalaDoc Reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)'s **Runtime Classes in Java vs. Runtime Types in Scala** part demonstrates the type conformance in similar case. In short, Scala compiler creates synthetic classes that are used at runtime in place of user-defined classes to be translated to equivalent Java Bytecode in cases mentioned in that part.

For the second simplication: this post [parameter-type-in-structural-refinement-may-not-refer-to-an-abstract-type-define-outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830731/parameter-type-in-structural-refinement-may-not-refer-to-an-abstract-type-defin) has given some detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, yeah using an abstract class or trait was about the best I could come up with too. I had hoped there was a better way. I will leave this open for a couple more days, and if there are no further suggestions, then I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: @adamretter, hey, just update my answer. Believe me, it's not for you to accept the answer. 
I just got trapped by why your two simplications could not work. After some productive study, I got it and
then the seemingly nasty solution just came unannounced.
Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @allen-chou I really like your explanation and having read the linked articles makes things much clearer. Good stuff :-)