# Why is instantiating a trait with default values in Scala a compilation error?

Tags: scala

The error can be reproduced by compiling the following code:

```
object ReproducingMyError {

  trait MyTrait[X] {
    def someFunc: X
  }

  def f[X] = new MyTrait[X] {
    var x: X = _
    def someFunc: X = x
  }

}
```

2 error messages were generated. Both point to

```
  def f[X] = new MyTrait[X] {
                 ^
```

The messages are similar:

`Error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement`

`Error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to a type member of that refinement`

Why is this a compilation error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7830731/1296806

Comment: To be clear, it's the setter that is the problem, `def x_=(x: X)`. That's the parameter in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to expose the `var` outside (which I assume you don't), then adding explicit return type fixes the problem:

```
def f[X]: MyTrait[X] = new MyTrait[X] {
  var x: X = _
  def someFunc: X = x
}
```

Without explicit type ascription, the compiler will infer the problematic "structural refinement", i.e. a type that looks like this: `MyTrait[X] { var x: X }`.

Yet another way to fix this is to declare the var as `private` - this way it won't be visible by anyone outside and, thus - won't be included in the inferred refinement type.

```
def f[X] = new MyTrait[X] {
  private var x: X = _
  def someFunc: X = x
}
```