# Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type

Tags: scala

The following piece of code does not work:

```
trait A {
  type C

  val Extract: {
    def unapply(c: C): Option[Int] 
  }
}
```

The error is the following:

> error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement

I wanted to write the above so that I force the user of trait A to define a object or a value which has an `unapply` method, so that I can use it in pattern matching.
I found two workarounds thanks to ["Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7830731/1287856) and [Scala: "Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2685804/1287856) (see below), but the first one makes inheritance of a trait compulsory, which is not feasible if I try to link to external libraries; and for the second, I loose the possibility to overriding `Extract` to put more methods into it.

**Workarounds**

```
trait A {
  type C

  trait Extractable {
    def unapply(c: C): Option[Int]
  }

  val Extract: Extractable
}

trait A {
  type C

  def extract(c: C): Option[Int]

  object Extract {
    def unapply(c: C): Option[Int]  = extract(c)
  }
}
```

Is there any way (maybe other than structural types) that I can express the idea that the user can implement `Extract` the way he wants, provided it has a method `unapply` of the requested signature?

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider type classes? `A` simply states that its type parameter must be "extractable", that is, there must be an implicit value of type `Extractable[C]` in scope (which only demands that you implement `unapply`). This can come from you, from some other library or from the user himself.

This however means that you can't simultaneously have more than one `Extractable[C]` for a given type `C`; that is, there is only one implementation for `Extractable` for some given type `C` (e.g. `Int`). Is this aligned with your use case?

```
trait Extractable[C] {
  def unapply(c: C): Option[Int]
}

// user can supply his own extractable:
implicit val myExtractableInt = new Extractable[Int] {
  def unapply(c: Int): Option[Int] = Some(c)
}

// class A is parameterized by some C 
// for which Extractable[C] must exist
class A[C : Extractable] {
  val c: C = ???
  implicitly[Extractable[C]].unapply(c)
}
```

EDIT:

To make `A` a trait, we need a (yet another) workaround:

```
trait Extractable[C] {
  def unapply(c: C): Option[Int]
}

// class A is parameterized by C
// for which Extractable[C] must exist
trait A[C] {
  implicit def e: Extractable[C]
  val c: C = ???
  e.unapply(c)
}

class SomeClass extends A[Int] {
  // we need an implicit Extractable[Int],
  // either from some import or custom one
  implicit def e = new Extractable[Int] {
    def unapply(c: Int): Option[Int] = Some(c)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that would almost work, except I need it to be a trait because there are several like `A` that I need to mix in one into another. And traits may not have implicit parameters nor parameters at all.

Comment: Does edited version help? It's still a workaround, but I think you should be pretty flexible with this.

Comment: Can you please use the same name as in the question? Instead of `e`, write `Extract` so that one can use it in pattern matching in `A`. Furthermore, it would be better to put the `Extractable` trait in `A` to be able to not disclose it somewhere else that the children of `A`